# Can I convert image to binary and send through websocket in c

Tags: c

I have a websocket server written in C and client also in C. I want to take a picture convert it to binary data , send it through the websocket and decode that picture so other client could see it. Is this possible to be implemented in C, because all the examples that I saw are written in C++ and C#. 
Thanks in advance

Comment: If you have websocket server and client already made, what prevents you from sending the binary data? If the implementation does not support binary transfers simply encode binary with base64 before sending and decode it at recipient.

Answer (score 3):

Then fun thing is, the picture most likely already is in binary.

As for the sending, it's no difference than any other socket communication. On the server you read X bytes from the file, and send X bytes to the client. On the client you read X bytes from the server, and write X bytes to a file (or buffer if you want the data in memory only).

Comment: Ok I see, may be I should try it write now, thanks for the fast reply :)